# How to send multiple emails to only selected user's emails in php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, email, checkbox

I am trying to send emails to only the users which i am selecting using checkbox from same index.php page. i am trying something here but i don't know that how to transfer and hold checked emails to "Bcc" field. here, is my code please have a look !

Php code for email (index.php) :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $to = "";

    $headers = "From:$name<$email>";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc: $selectedemailsall\r\n";

    $message = "Name: $name\n\n Email: $email \n\n Subject : $subject \n\n Message : $comments";
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        echo "Email Send";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error : Please Try Again !";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Code for form (index.php) :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Mail Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form action="" method="post" >
 <p>Name :<br>
 <input type="text" name="name" id=""></p>
 <p>Email :<br>
 <input type="text" name="email" id=""></p>
 <p>Subject :<br>
 <input type="text" name="subject" id=""></p>
 <p>Comments :<br>
 <textarea name="comments" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Send Email" name="SubmitEmail"></p>
 </form>    

 <form action="#" method="post">
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
 $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "");
 $db = mysqli_select_db("testdb", $connection);
 $query = mysqli_query("select * from users", $connection);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
 echo "
 <input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='{$row['email']}'>
 <label>{$row['username']}</label><br/>
 ";
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submituserchk']))
{
  //to run PHP script on submit
  if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
{
  // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
  foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selectedemails)
  {
    $selectedemailsall = $selectedemails.",";
    //echo $selectedemailsall;
  }
 }
}
?>
</div> <!-- End of RightUsersDivWithCheckBox -->
 <input type="submit" name="submituserchk" style="margin-left: 87%; margin-top: 20px;" value="Done"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any solution please how to do this ? right now when i click "Done" and submit emails nothing happens and i don't want to click "Done" button after selecting emails. I just select emails and they goes to "Bcc" field in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got an answer to my own question. below is my code,

**Display username, emails with checkbox from database :**

```
$getemail = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users",$connection);
if(!$getemail) die('MsSQL Error: ' . mysqli_error());
echo '<div class="AllUserDiv" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:400px;"><table class="table table-bordered">';
echo "<thead>
    <tr>
    <th><input type='checkbox' onchange='checkedbox(this)' name='chk' /> </th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

 if(mysqli_num_rows($getemail) == 0)
 {
   echo "<tbody><tr><td colspan='3'> No Data Available</td></tr></tbody>"; 
 }

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getemail))
{
  echo "<tbody><tr><td><input value='".$row['email']."' type='checkbox' name='check[]' checked /> </td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td></tr></tbody>";   
}
```

**Email Form :**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<p style="margin-top:30px;">Email Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" value="" class="form-control" /></p>
<p>Email Content: <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" style="width:100%;"></textarea></p>
<center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email Now" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript for making checkbox selection :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function checkedbox(element)
 {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById('input');
  if(element.checked)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++ )
    {
        if(checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
        {
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(i)
            if(checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
            {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Bcc header for many users. Yo can make is:

Your form:

```
...
<input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="foo@host.tld"> - foo@host.tld
<input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="bar@host.tld"> - bar@host.tld
<input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="baz@host.tld"> - baz@host.tld
...
```

Your backend code:

```
...
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST) && is_array($_POST['email'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['email'] as $to) {
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
...
```

All emails sent separatelly for all recipients. This is flexible case for your application -- you can check for each send status.

Comment: You are right but i don't want to display to much emails to every one when someone got an email he able to see how much other emails in "To". but in "Bcc" its hidden so, no one able to see it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly done here ? After checked the emails what happens here ?

Comment: Here -- all emails sent separatelly for all recipients. This is flexible case for your application -- you can check for each send status.

Comment: OK i can implement it on server and see for any issues.

Comment: Its not working the else condition runs "Error : Please Try Again !" I don't troubleshoot where i am wrong ?

Comment: Can you show (e.g. via pastebin.com or here) full actual code for review, comment and fix?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to do that because for email functionality it needs live server so it may have my db credentials. but, above is my full code and its working fine. But actually after clicking "Done" i echo $selectedemailsall and it may have all selected emails inside with separate semicolon but when i pass $selectedemailsall to "Bcc" then i got "Notice: Undefined variable: selectedemailsall in......." So, where i am wrong ?

Comment: Deep thanks for giving solution it helps me to prepare a right solution for my problem.

Comment: @John120 OK )))